# How can I transfer my Google Chrome bookmarks to my iPad?

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, bookmarks

I have been looking around for a method and haven't been able to find one, any suggestions?

Comment: This article maybe of assistance http://www.everythingicafe.com/sync-chrome-bookmarks-with-iphone-or-ipad/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Google Chrome](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/chrome/id535886823?mt=8)

....is now available for iOS.

Just activate (bookmarks) synchronisation on your PC and iPad. Go to *New Tab > Favorites > Computer Favorites.*

> **From the App Store description:**
>
> - Sign in to Chrome to sync your open tabs, bookmarks, passwords, and omnibox data from your computer to your iPhone, iPod touch, or iPad. Pick up right where you left off.
> - Send pages from Chrome on your computer to your iPhone, iPod touch, or iPad with one click and read them on the go, even if you’re offline.

Answer (score 3):

If you want them synced (but not built-in Mobile Safari), you may use [XMarks](http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=1609).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to stick with Safari on the iPad, you'll need to sync via iTunes.

Take your Chrome bookmarks and save them to an HTML bookmark file.  Then import these into Safari (on a Mac) or Internet Explorer (on Windows).  Then, in your iTunes sync options, under the Info "tab", choose to sync your bookmarks.

What I personally do, though, is to use [Pinboard](http://pinboard.in) to store all of my bookmarks online.  I can access it from any device with no syncing required.

Comment: Also assuming you want to stick to Safari on the iPad, and that you have iCloud...you should be able to right click on a URL in Chrome and click "Add to Reading List".  

There is probably a way to do this with automator/Apple script for your already stored bookmarks, if you save them to an external file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Apollo browser](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id470154924) for iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone might be interested. I found a simple solution for accessing Chrome bookmarks online. It only requires Dropbox account (or any similar service with a public folder).

You can find details on [the Chrome Bookmarks Online github page.](https://github.com/gornostal/Chrome-Bookmarks-Online)

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to manually backup ipad, iphone or ios chrome bookmarks, this is the way i found. You need a file manager or ifile installed first you must find google application folder, if u have ifile installed first go to settings and activate "Show Hidden Files" then search for word stable.app and u will find chrome location that is something like this 85067e01-685f-4c16-8093-89c698cb62ca/Library/Application Support/Google/Default 
The Bookmarks and bookmarks.bak files that contains your bookmarks are stored in folder Default you can copy that files for an easy restore after reinstall chrome or reset ur device

Answer (score 0):

1 Export the bookmarks from Chrome to your computer

[image]

2 Import the [bookmark to the iPad](http://www.copytrans.net/support/import-chrome-bookmarks-to-iphone/)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this require some additional software?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Chrome Sync** feature to migrate `History`, `Open Tabs`, `Bookmarks` and more between the various instances of **Chrome** on multiple devices. `Chrome Sync` uses your `Google Account` in the cloud to facilitate this transfer.

I wrote a walkthough of how to set up Chrome Sync on the following StackExchange question:

> **[How to navigate a lot of tabs in Google Chrome on iOS (iPad)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/270991/222512)**
>   https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/270991/222512

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows computer, follow these steps:

1. [Download iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/HT204283). Connect your iPad to the computer with the lightning cable and open iCloud. You will be greeted with this screen:

[image]

2. Scroll down to Bookmarks and click **Options...**.

[image]

3. If Chrome is already selected, uncheck and check it again, else select it and press **OK**.

[image]

4. Click on **Apply** button.

[image]

5. Now the bookmarks will started syncing. They should show up in Safari on your iPad.

[image]